# Android ViewPager on a Null Object Reference

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an activity that require a viewPager that includes 2 fragments on it, but when I setting up ViewPager adapter in onCreateView, its always null. I use ButterKnife for bind its layout to activity.

The error was when this code executed

```
viewPager.setAdapter(vp_adapter);
```

Error in Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

MainActivity.java

```
@BindView(R.id.tab_layout)
TabLayout tabLayout;

@BindView(R.id.view_pager)
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    handleViewPager();
    handlePosition();
}


private void handleViewPager(){
    ViewPagerAdapter vp_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(vp_adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topUpHeader"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#1e84d4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Top Up"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/topUpHeader">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#000000">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewpager_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

How do it can be done ?

edited: 
so its just run with onCreateView like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager   = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout   = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    ViewPagerAdapter vp_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(vp_adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    handlePosition();
}
```

Comment: did you initialize your viewpager with butterknife like @BindView( R.id.view_pager) Viewpager viewpager at the top.

Comment: I did, at first I think its something wrong with ButterKnife so I use findViewById instead of ButterKnife but still have the same error

Comment: for test , find your viewpager id just above the line where you initialize the viewpager adapter and check whether the error is still there or not.

Comment: Hi, its working somehow, I just deleted the ButterKnife and use findViewById as your advice. But the question is why it cant use ButterKnife ?

Comment: Butterknife should work, as your code seems fine with butterknife, there may be some problem during the injection of butterknife or sometimes you have to `invalidate cache and restart` after injecting the butterknife to code.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to find view. I see that you are using ButterKnife view binding.

So first declare global variable `viewPager` using below code.

```
@BindView(R.id. view_pager) 
ViewPager viewPager;
```

Butterknife SDK in gradle.

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Comment: i am sorry, i forgot to bring BindView code, consider to check the update

Comment: implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'

Comment: You are using wrong sdk for annotationProcessor. Please check this answer again I have fixed compiler sdk too. Try with that and let us know.

Comment: try clean and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Butterknife the wrong way. You need to define every view in your xml which you want to use in your java file. Define viewPager as `@BindView(R.id.view_pager) ViewPager viewPager;`. Same goes for tabLayout. Consider using data binding if you want to use `viewPager` directly.

Comment: hi, thank you for your response, check the update please I forgot to attach its BindView